My website is not showing up after uploading my project to cpanel
I have uploaded my django project as a zip file and extracted in the home directory of the root server. My website is showing up without the images and the css design files.

The root directory of my webpage in remote server is above. In every app inside the project, there is seperate static and template files as shown in the django documentation. But I am having issue with showing the images and css design files for the project.
After the quick research I have done, I realized that I should put the images and css files to the public_html file in the root directory. Can anyone help me out with the issue ?
For example, the about page's directory is provided below.


I found the solution, in settings.py, we need to configure the static root for remote server's home directory and the public_html folder, then we need to run
python manage.py collectstatic

